# Date compare in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a string of date which I have converted to javascript date. I'm trying to compare it but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var str = "06/23/2016";

var parts = str.split("/");

var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),
                  parseInt(parts[0], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(parts[1], 10));
var now = Date();


if(dt > now) { alert("the date is greater than now");} else { alert ("the date is not greater than now");}

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With your code your compare the stringified version of the dates. Use `dt.getTime() > now.getTime()` to compare.

Comment: Thanks, it says - it has no method of getTime though.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work ? What is the actual problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Date()` returns a string representation of the current date:

```
> Date()
'Sun May 17 2015 15:05:25 GMT+0200'
```

What you want to do instead is create a new Date object using the `new` operator:

```
> new Date()
Date 2015-05-17T13:06:42.788Z
```

This object can then be compared to another `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `new`

```
var now = new Date();
```